# Accelerate parallel processing in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing

I was hoping to use parallel processing to accelerate a `for loop`, but as seen in the example below, it is much slower that the loop. Is there anything wrong with my parallel processing approach? Are there better solutions?

The **goal** here is to update a column of a dataframe using a pre-defined functions that operates on multiple other columns of the dataframe.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import timeit

inputs = [range(50),range(90),range(30)]
inputs_list = list(itertools.product(*inputs))
Index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inputs_list,names={"a", "b", "c"})
df = pd.DataFrame(index = Index)
df['Output'] = 0

start_p = timeit.timeit()

def Addition(A,B,C):
    df.loc[A,B,C]['Output']=A+B+C
    return df.loc[A,B,C]['Output']

num_workers = mp.cpu_count()  
pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)
df['Output'] = pool.starmap(Addition,inputs_list) # specify the function and arguments to map 
pool.close()
pool.join()

end_p = timeit.timeit()
print(end_p - start_p)

start_l = timeit.timeit()

for A in range(50):
  for B in range(90):
    for C in range(30):
      df.loc[A,B,C]['Output']=A+B+C

end_l = timeit.timeit()
print(end_l - start_l)
```

Comment: I was getting nonsensical results on my machine using timeit (negative numbers) so I switched to datetime. I also constructed Pool() with no arguments (it's more portable that way). My execution time for the multiprocessing was 2.6s and for the loops 13.6s. I can only guess that the performance will vary considerably depending on your system architecture. (I'm running on 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W with 32GB 2666 MHz DDR4 RAM)

Comment: Thanks, it might be my system architecture then! Because I get higher numbers than yours and the parallel processing takes almost 40% more than the time of loop ...

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to first prepare dict, then make dataframe out of it. Adding rows to df one by one is slow.

And as DarkKnight mentioned in a comment, `timeit` does not make sense here. I use `time.time()`

```
start_l = time.time()
dict_to_df = {}
for A in range(50):
  for B in range(90):
    for C in range(30):
      dict_to_df[A,B,C] = A+B+C
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_to_df, orient='index', columns=['Output'])

end_l = time.time()
print(end_l - start_l)
```

0.26 sec on my Machine

Assuming dataframe index is well ordered, you can just do something like this, using `numpy` vectorization:

```
import numpy as np
start_l = time.time()
a = np.arange(50)
b = np.arange(90)
c = np.arange(30)
a_plus_b = np.add.outer(a, b).flatten()
a_plus_b_plus_c = np.add.outer(a_plus_b, c).flatten()
df['Output'] = a_plus_b_plus_c

end_l = time.time()
print(end_l - start_l)
```

0.00044

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, the performance is dependent on the function complexity. So while for simple addition, dictionary approach works better, for my function/procedure it does not.